# Autohide launcher is cut off / clipped in 14.04

Tags: unity, 14.04, launcher, autohide

With autohide enabled on 14.04 (Unity 3d), my launcher ends up cut off, clipped, ie. doesn't come completely back out of hiding.  It still functions fine... but it's about 20% still off the edge of the screen.

It did not do this at first, just started to today.  Nothing I can think of has changed though.

If I disable autohide, the launcher shows up fine.  I tried with different sized icons and had the same problem.

I have a GTX 760 with the 331.38 proprietary and tested nvidia drivers driving  mirrored 1080p displays that both show the same thing.

[image: clipped launcher]

Anyone run into this, or have any ideas?

Comment: Just figured out that I can't drag apps to it either when it's on autohide.  Works fine when I turn it off.

Comment: Same behaviour here, with intel graphics. Possibly a bug?

Comment: fwiw, it has come and gone for me.  If I turn it off and reboot, then turn it back on, sometimes it clears up and doesn't come back for a long time.  It's been working right for me for the past week or more - so fingers crossed.